# Declaring m-suffix for a decimal type dynamically

Tags: c#, runtime, decimal, suffix

If I want use a decimal-literal in code, I use `m-suffix`, for example

```
decimal test = 1000m;
```

Is there any way to declare this `m-suffix` dynamically in run time?
Somethings like this one:

```
decimal DeclareDecimal_M_SuffixFor(int decimalPoints)
{
    decimal result =  10 * decimalPoints m;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to do that in this function ? If you do, then just cast explicitly : `(decimal)decimalPoints` . But this case is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,  `decimalPoints m` is invalid syntax - but you can use casting

```
decimal result =  10 * (decimal)decimalPoints;
```

or in this case better: a `decimal` multiplied with a `int` results into a `decimal`

```
decimal result =  10m * decimalPoints;
```